# Transferring blogspot blog to own domain blog hosted by blogger

Tags: domains, blogger, transfer

I currently have a blogspot.com blog and I'm thinking of transferring everything to a custom domain blog, but one which is hosted by Blogger. Will my old posts and images be automatically transferred to the new blog?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The blog remains unchanged, it's the domain you use to get to it that changes.